# Detect node with Wp All Import / Wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, wpallimport

i a have a problem with an import.
I didn't have the type of the product like <product_type>value</product_type>
But i have some nodes with :

```
<product_type>
<reference>value</reference>
<price>value</price>
</product_type>
```

I need to get the product type in my mapping...

Do you have any idea if you already use this script in wordpress ?

Thank for your help,
Regards,

Fred

Need to check and get the name of the node.